# Remove an item from generic Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a generic class defined like this

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : ICompareable
{
  T[] data;

  public AddData(T[] values)
  {
     data = values;
  }
}
```

In mainForm, I create 3 random numbers, and add them as values, lets say 1, 2 and 3. So my T[] data; will look like this: [0]1 [1]2 [2]3

What I want to do is to remove 1 of these values from the array, how do I do that when I'm using generics. Lets say I want to remove 3 from the array so it would look like this[0]1 [1]2

Comment: Actually, you *could* do something along the lines of `data = (new List<T>(data)).RemoveValue(value).ToArray()`, but that would be very(!) inefficient, so better use a List<T> instead as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to look like this (I also implemented Frederik's suggestion of using a List instead of a array.

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : ICompareable
{
  List<T> data;

  public AddData(T value)
  {
     data.Add(value);
  }
  public RemoveData(T value)
  {
     data.Remove(value);
  }
}
```

If for some reasaon, you insist on using an array, the remove method may look something like this

```
public RemoveData(T value)
{
  data = data.Where( e => e.CompareTo(value) != 0).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you use a generic List (`List<T>`) instead of the array as a private member of your class to hold the data ?

As it is a private member, the 'outside world' cannot access  the list, and you will have a much easier life since a List allows you to Add and Remove items easily.

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : ICompareable
{
  private List<T> data = new List<T>();

  public AddData(params T[] values)
  {
      data.AddRange (values);
  }

  public RemoveData( T value )
  {
     data.Remove (value);
  }

  public RemoveData( params T[] values )
  {
      for( int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++ ) 
      {
          data.Remove (values[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

Once you've done this, you can use the `Add` member-method of the `List` to add items, and the `Remove` member method to remove items.  Simple as that.

I've used the `params` keyword in the `AddData` method so that you can do this:

```
var x = new MyGenericClass<int>();

x.AddData(1);
x.AddData(2, 3, 4);
x.AddData(somIntegerList.ToArray());
```

Comment: ... or `LinkedList<T>` or `Hashset<T>`. You should see what you need from this private data, and choose the correct structure for the task.

Comment: I don't think that this was the point of the exercise...

Answer (score 1):

I kind of had the same question, because I was writing a dynamically sized array to practice creating generic classes.

I found that you can either: move all of the elements down and then set the last element equal to `default(T)`, or create a new array of size-1 to be filled with the remaining elements.

Ex:

```
public class Array<T>
{
    private T[] _array { get; set; }
    private int _max { get; set; }
    private int _size { get; set; }

    public Array()
    {
        _max = 10;
        _array = new T[_max];
        _size = 0;
    } 

    public T Remove(int i)
    {
        if (i >= _size || i < 0) return default(T);

        var tmp = _array[i];

        for (var j = i; j < _size-1; ++j)
        {
            _array[j] = _array[j + 1];
        }
        _array[_size - 1] = default(T);   
        _size--;
        return tmp;
    }
}

Or...
public T Remove(int i) {
  var tmp = new T[_size-1];

  for(var j=0; j < i; ++j) 
  {
     tmp[j] = _array[j];
  }

  var result = _array[i];

  for(var j=i+1; j < _size-1; ++j) 
  {
     tmp[j] = _array[j];
  }
  _array = null;
  _array = tmp;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Helpful. Besides, this indeed answers the original question